# I have no interiors lights and my fuses are OK, what could be the cause?

Tags: electrical, hyundai, lights, interior, elantra

I have a 2006 Hyundai Elantra Sedan.  The gauges, courtesy lights, door locks, electric windows, and taillights do not work.

1. Does it have a reset switch for my electrical problem?
2. Does anyone have any advice of where to start?

Comment: Does the engine run? What fuses have you checked? Cars have up to a hundred fuses separated over several fuse boxes. Further the electrical system used to be powered up through the ignition switch, now a days the ignition switch tells someone (PCM BCM Other) i want to power up and they then activate the relays to power up. Have you checked the fuses to the "someones" and the relays?

Comment: I would have though it would be something obvious maybe a master fuse or live feed to a fuse/distribution box, or a missing earth.

Answer (score 2):

All those items that do not work are powered by the passenger compartment fuse box, this is powered by the Ignition switch, which is powered by a 40 amp fusible link, I suspect a ignition switch issue.

[image]